# check if string contains only numbers, else show message

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a simple form, which performs a calculation when a digit is pressed, however this should only happen when numbers are typed, if a letter is added i would like for a notification to appear. Is there a simple function to do this?

Form

```
    <input onKeyPress="return onlyNumbers()" onKeyUp="calc()" id="value1" type="text" name="value1">
    <select onChange="calc()" id="manipulator" name="manipulator">
        <option value="commission">Commission</option>
        <option value="cost">Return</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

calc function

```
function calc(){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    val1 = document.getElementById("value1").value;
    mani = document.getElementById("manipulator").value;

    if (val1 != ""){
        document.getElementById("resp").innerHTML="Calculating...";
        queryPath = "comCalcServ.php?value1="+val1+"&manipulator="+mani;

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                document.getElementById("resp").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET",queryPath);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

I am currently looking at the isNaN function but not familiar with the JS syntax so unsure where to use it.

Comment: @DenysSéguret that won't work. Try `parseFloat('12xxxx12')` in your console and check what that returns :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
//add inside your calc function
val1 = document.getElementById("value1").value;
if(/^\d+$/.test(val1)) {
 //proceed with rest of code
}
else {
 alert("Invalid");
 return false;
}
```

Comment: Stupid question but would this be inserted into the calc function? im unfamiliar with js.

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple one

```
if(val1.match(/^\d+$/)) {
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the above code did not work in my case . so i made few changes .
i just changed regex to `/^[0-9]*$/.test(val1)` and it worked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11970127)

Comment: not having enough reputation doen't mean i am wrong. i just wrote the lines which did my job